# Visual Studio 2013 Strip'em Plugin Issue Win10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, plugins, windows-10, line-endings

Hey I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and Windows 10 installed. I am unable to install the [VS Plugin "Strip'em"](http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php).

It says that I don't have the required .Net Framework. but I've installed all frameworks 3.5(2,3), 4 and 4.5 etc. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's the log file context.

```
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - -------------------------------------------
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - Initializing Install...
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - Extension Details...
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Identifier      : 003a0f14-2226-41a9-8f63-dce243af9932
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Name            : Strip'em
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Author          : grebulon.com
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Version         : 1.0
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Description     : Visual Studio 2013 package. Save files with Unix or Windows line endings.
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Locale          : en-US
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   MoreInfoURL     : http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   InstalledByMSI  : False
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5]
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   Supported Products : 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -           Version : [12.0]
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -   References      : 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       -------------------------------------------------------
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.12.0
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF 12.0
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       Version      : [12.0]
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       MoreInfoURL  : 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM -       Nested       : No
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - 
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - Searching for applicable products...
9/6/2015 2:36:46 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
9/6/2015 2:36:48 PM - The extension with ID '003a0f14-2226-41a9-8f63-dce243af9932' is not installed to Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.
9/6/2015 2:36:48 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
9/6/2015 2:36:48 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
9/6/2015 2:36:48 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
9/6/2015 2:36:48 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
9/6/2015 2:36:51 PM - The following target products have been selected...
9/6/2015 2:36:51 PM -   Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
9/6/2015 2:36:51 PM - 
9/6/2015 2:36:51 PM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013...
9/6/2015 2:36:51 PM - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingTargetFrameworkException: The extension 'Strip'em' requires a version of the .NET Framework that is not installed.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForValidDotNetFramework(IExtension extension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForInstallBlockers(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, Boolean isNestedExtension, Boolean& olderVersionInstalled)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean perMachine, Boolean isNestedExtension, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, UInt64 totalBytesToWrite, UInt64& totalBytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Comment: I have fixed the installer the way Jesse suggested and uploaded it to http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php. Please verify that it works for you.

Comment: @grebulon thanks it works fine now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are running on Windows 10 and thus are at .NET 4.6. The extension explicitly takes a dependency on .NET 4.5 in its dependency manifest:

```
<Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="4.5" />
```

The simplest way to get it installed is to open the `vsix` using something like 7zip, select the `extension.vsixmanifest` and right-click and choose <kbd>edit...</kbd> from the context menu.

Remove the line mentioned above so that the manifest reads:

```
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="003a0f14-2226-41a9-8f63-dce243af9932" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="grebulon.com" />
    <DisplayName>Strip'em</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Visual Studio 2013 package. Save files with Unix or Windows line endings.</Description>
    <MoreInfo>http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php</MoreInfo>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="12.0" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.12.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 12.0" Version="12.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" Path="Stripem.pkgdef" />
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

And close notepad (or whichever editor popped up). 7zip will ask whether you want to update the archive, choose <kbd>yes</kbd>. Now try installing the extension again.

The dependency should probably have used:

```
<Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="[4.5,]" />
```

To make sure that **at least** 4.5 is installed, or:

```
<Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="[4.5,5.0)" />
```

To say that any framework version with major version 4 higher than 4.5 will do.

More on the [syntax of the dependency tag can be found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/08/update-for-extension-authors-vsix-manifest-version-ranges.aspx).

Because Framework 4.6 is an in-place installation, it will update the 4.5 framework to 4.6, which is causing this issue. Personally I would not have taken a dependency on the framework version in this case, as Visual Studio 2013 won't function without framework 4.5 installed.

Comment: Contacted the author @grebulon and sent him an updated vsix.

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks it works absolutely fine now. :)